# Multithreading - writing to a file for each thread Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file-io

I have a Python 3 script which has the following code:

```py
from subprocess import check_output, Popen, CalledProcessError
from os import getenv, mkdir, path
from time import sleep, time
from threading import Thread

def pgrep(proc_name):
    try:
        check_output(["pgrep", proc_name])
        return True
    except CalledProcessError:
        return False

def watch_dog(proc_name, polling_rate, CONFIG_DIR):
    print("Thread " + proc_name + " Started")
    start_time = 0
    end_time = 0
    total_time = 0
    while True:
        if (pgrep(proc_name) and (start_time == 0)):
            start_time = time()
            print("TIMING " + proc_name)
        elif ((not pgrep(proc_name)) and (start_time != 0)):
            end_time = time()
            total_time = str(end_time - start_time)
            print("Done timing " + proc_name)
            print("TIME: " + total_time)
            try:
                with open(CONFIG_DIR + proc_name + "-time.log", "w+") as log_file:
                    log_file.write(total_time)
                    log_file.write("\n")
                    log_file.flush()
            except:
                print("CANNOT WRITE TO FILE")
            start_time = 0
            end_time = 0
            total_time = 0
        sleep(polling_rate)

for each in processes:
        globals()[each] = Thread(target=watch_dog, args=(each, polling_rate, CONFIG_DIR,))
        globals()[each].start()
```

Everything works perfectly, except that I cannot write to any files from the `watch_dog` function. I have done some research, and most things are pointing towards needing a separate thread to write to the file others are wanting to write to. However, all these examples I find are for specifically multiple threads writing to one file. I, however, want one file per thread.

Is there some way to circumvent this issue or do I have to have a thread for writing to each separate file?

Comment: what's the issue? the files are being created but not written to?

Comment: @gold_cy no the files aren't being created at all. And no error is being thrown when writes are attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered what my problem was. On this line:

```py
with open(CONFIG_DIR + proc_name + "-time.log", "w+") as log_file:
```

CONFIG_DIR does not end with a forward slash ("/") and so the files WERE being created, just in the parent directory and with a name I did not expect. it was a simple fix:

```py
with open(CONFIG_DIR + "/" + proc_name + "-time.log", "w+") as log_file:
```

Moral of the story: check your file paths.